# System.OverflowException in one project -- while works in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, exception

I have a weird problem. I have been searching the internet for a good and fast Gaussian blur algorithm. And I finally found one!

So what I did was to try it in a new project - it worked just fine.

When I then was going to import the class into my main project and then tried it, I got a `System.OverflowException`. I'm finding this really weird that it works in one project, but not in another.

Here's the algorithm:

(I am calling the function almost the same. I tried calling it the exact same way, but I still got an exception)

```
public static void FastBlur(Bitmap SourceImage, int radius)
    {
        var rct = new Rectangle(0, 0, SourceImage.Width, SourceImage.Height);
        var dest = new int[rct.Width * rct.Height];
        var source = new int[rct.Width * rct.Height];
        var bits = SourceImage.LockBits(rct, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, source, 0, source.Length);
        SourceImage.UnlockBits(bits);
        if (radius < 1) return;

        int w = rct.Width;
        int h = rct.Height;
        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;
        var r = new int[wh];
        var g = new int[wh];
        var b = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p1, p2, yi;
        var vmin = new int[max(w, h)];
        var vmax = new int[max(w, h)];

        var dv = new int[256 * div];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * div; i++)
        {
            dv[i] = (i / div);
        }

        int yw = yi = 0;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
        { // blur horizontal
            rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++)
            {
                int p = source[yi + min(wm, max(i, 0))];
                rsum += (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                gsum += (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                bsum += p & 0x0000ff;
            }
            for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                if (y == 0)
                {
                    vmin[x] = min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                    vmax[x] = max(x - radius, 0);
                }
                p1 = source[yw + vmin[x]];
                p2 = source[yw + vmax[x]];

                rsum += ((p1 & 0xff0000) - (p2 & 0xff0000)) >> 16;
                gsum += ((p1 & 0x00ff00) - (p2 & 0x00ff00)) >> 8;
                bsum += (p1 & 0x0000ff) - (p2 & 0x0000ff);
                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
        { // blur vertical
            rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            int yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++)
            {
                yi = max(0, yp) + x;
                rsum += r[yi];
                gsum += g[yi];
                bsum += b[yi];
                yp += w;
            }
            yi = x;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                dest[yi] = (int)(0xff000000u | (uint)(dv[rsum] << 16) | (uint)(dv[gsum] << 8) | (uint)dv[bsum]); // <--- Here's where I get the exception
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    vmin[y] = min(y + radius + 1, hm) * w;
                    vmax[y] = max(y - radius, 0) * w;
                }
                p1 = x + vmin[y];
                p2 = x + vmax[y];

                rsum += r[p1] - r[p2];
                gsum += g[p1] - g[p2];
                bsum += b[p1] - b[p2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        // copy back to image
        var bits2 = SourceImage.LockBits(rct, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Marshal.Copy(dest, 0, bits2.Scan0, dest.Length);
        SourceImage.UnlockBits(bits);
    }
```

Here's how I call the function:

```
public Bitmap DownloadBlurredImage(List<string> uris, int blurradius)
    {
        Uri urlUri = new Uri(uris.ElementAt(0));
        if (RandomSelect == true)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            urlUri = new Uri(uris.ElementAt(r.Next(0, uris.Count - 1)));
        }

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateDefault(urlUri);
        webRequest.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream mystream;

        if ((mystream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()) != null)
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(mystream); 
            imageFilters.FastBlur(b, 10); //<--- here's where I'm calling
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is acting up? I myself have NO clue..

Comment: The exception means you're putting a value too big into a variable - for example, an int.  This is entirely feasible doing image processing [and would be variable based on the image being blurred].  At which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone If you scroll as much as you can to the right in the algorithm-part, you'll see that I've marked the line which throws the exception.

Comment: When you copy back the image data `SourceImage.UnlockBits(bits);` you should use bits2 ...

Comment: @Didier If that's the case - why does it work just fine in other projects. That's the part I really find weird

Comment: I don't know whether this is the source of your error but when I tested your code it fired a memory violation exception.

Comment: @Didier ??? Wow, as if it wasn't strange enough..

Comment: @Tokfrans Your first project where it works is a x64? I just tested in 64 bits and the bug occurs randomly. Sometimes it works sometimes not. I think as UnlockBits was already called on the `bits` and then LockBits was called on `bits2` the behavior is not certain and depends on the memory configuration at that moment. But anyway you should use `bits2`.

Comment: @Didier Nope, it was x86. Tried changing from x86->x64 on my main program but no change. I still get that exception.

Comment: You kind of half attack the problem yourself.  Casting using uint but then storing the result in an int.  int has half the range of a uint - see answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using signed 'ints' to hold unsigned data - if the MSB is set, the overflow will occur.  Use unsigned ints (for example for `dest`), or surround in an `unchecked { }` directive.

Comment: Using Uint's for the dest variable gave me errors at ' Marshal.Copy(dest, 0, bits2.Scan0, dest.Length);' saying that "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr[], int, int)' has some invalid arguments"